# how can make regex or program replace for the following logic

Tags: php, json, api, ckeditor

I am using Ckeditor image upload functionality in my admin panel.
everything is working fine as per admin panel requirements but in my REST API i need the full url of image file inserted inside ckeditor using ckfinder plugin
following format is stored in db

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;img alt=&quot;&quot; src=&quot;/food/kcfinder/uploads/images/karunanidhi-759.jpg&quot; style=&quot;height:422px; width:759px
```

what I try :
i used following to replace the $quot;

```
$product_des = htmlspecialchars_decode(str_replace("&quot;", "\"", $product_des));
```

but here am facing a problem which is when i replace $quote; it is working fine but i want to replace the  src as full path so it will work in my API
**src="/food/kcfinder/uploads/images/karunanidhi-759.jpg"**
 **TO**
**src=www.mydomain/food/kcfinder/uploads/images/karunanidhi-759.jpg**
is there any way to do this help me out please am stucked

MY API CODE AS PER REQUIRMENT:

```
$product_des = $records1['description'];
$product_des = htmlspecialchars_decode(str_replace("&quot;", "\"", $product_des));
        $remove[] = "src=";
        $srcfull='src='.$serverimg;
        $product_des =(str_replace($remove, $srcfull, $product_des));
        print_r($product_des);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which  version of ck editor you are using? give us more details

i suggest you to do try in this way

```
$remove[] = "'";
$remove[] = '"';
$remove[] = "`"; // just as another example
$res_address = str_replace($remove, "", $description);
```

you can replace as per your requirement.

Comment: thanks for your reply Jagdish but here i don't want to replace the sign i want to add path of my url just before the   /uploads/ to mydomain.com/uploads/

Comment: so can you show me code of your REST API so we can help you out

Comment: thanks for help jagdish but still am stucked at the url part

Comment: let me see what can i do for you i will replay soon